# List of Files in Folder Sub Folder in Directory

Tags: excel, vba

I am using this code to list out all the files in Folder and Sub Folder in Excel. This code is working fine. I want to leave one **blank row** for each sub folder. currently its list out continuously in all the rows. Please help.

```
Sub HyperlinkDirectory()

Dim fPath As String
Dim fType As String
Dim fname As String
Dim NR As Long
Dim AddLinks As Boolean

'Select folder
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
         .InitialFileName = "C:\2009\"
        .Show
        If .SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
            fPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With

'Types of files
    fType = Application.InputBox("What kind of files? Type the file extension to collect" _
            & vbLf & vbLf & "(Example:  pdf, doc, txt, xls, *)", "File Type", "pdf", Type:=2)
    If fType = "False" Then Exit Sub

'Option to create hyperlinks
    AddLinks = MsgBox("Add hyperlinks to the file listing?", vbYesNo) = vbYes

'Create report
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    NR = 5
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        .Range("A:C").Clear
        .[A1] = "Directory"
        .[B1] = fPath
        .[A2] = "File type"
        .[B2] = fType
        .[A4] = "File"
        .[B4] = "Modified"

        Call FindFilesAndAddLinks(fPath, fType, NR, AddLinks)




        .Range("A:B").Columns.AutoFit
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Private Sub FindFilesAndAddLinks(fPath As String, fType As String, ByRef NR As Long, AddLinks As Boolean)
Dim fname As String
Dim oFS As New FileSystemObject
Dim oDir


    'Files under current dir
    fname = Dir(fPath & "*." & fType)
    With Sheets("Sheet1")

        Do While Len(fname) > 0
          'filename
            .Range("A" & NR) = fname
          'modified
            .Range("B" & NR) = FileDateTime(fPath & fname)
          'hyperlink
            .Range("A" & NR).Select
            If AddLinks Then .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, _
                Address:=fPath & fname, _
                TextToDisplay:=fPath & fname
          'set for next entry
            NR = NR + 1
            fname = Dir
        Loop

        'Files under sub dir
        Set oDir = oFS.GetFolder(fPath)
        For Each oSub In oDir.SubFolders
            Call FindFilesAndAddLinks(oSub.Path & "\", fType, NR, AddLinks)
        Next oSub
    End With


End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The changed `FindFilesAndAddLinks` below will create the following format:

`FolderRoot\Folder1\Subfolder1`
`FolderRoot\Folder1\Subfolder1\FirstFileFound`
`FolderRoot\Folder1\Subfolder1\SecondFileFound`

`FolderRoot\Folder2\Subfolder2`
`FolderRoot\Folder2\Subfolder2\FirstFileFound`
`FolderRoot\Folder2\Subfolder2\SecondFileFound`
`...`

New macro:

```
Private Sub FindFilesAndAddLinks(fPath As String, fType As String, ByRef NR As Long, AddLinks As Boolean)
Dim fname As String
Dim oFS As New FileSystemObject
Dim oDir

'Files under current dir
fname = Dir(fPath & "*." & fType)
With Sheets("Sheet1")

    'Write folder name
    .Range("A" & NR) = fPath
    NR = NR + 1

    Do While Len(fname) > 0
      'filename
        If .Range("A" & NR) <> "" Then Debug.Print "Overwriting " & NR
        .Range("A" & NR) = fname
      'modified
        .Range("B" & NR) = FileDateTime(fPath & fname)
      'hyperlink
        .Range("A" & NR).Select
        If AddLinks Then .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, _
            Address:=fPath & fname, _
            TextToDisplay:=fPath & fname
      'set for next entry
        NR = NR + 1
        fname = Dir
    Loop

    'Files under sub dir
    Set oDir = oFS.GetFolder(fPath)
    For Each oSub In oDir.SubFolders
        NR = NR + 1
        Call FindFilesAndAddLinks(oSub.Path & "\", fType, NR, AddLinks)
    Next oSub
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: CLR thank you so much, your code is working fine, but i am getting debug error  under 'Files under current dir
"fname = Dir(fPath & "*." & fType)" and "For Each oSub In oDir.SubFolders"

Comment: Are you using the latest version, which adds the folder name?

Comment: Your new code working fine. Now its showing the folder name thank you so much.............

Comment: I have added hyperlink for folder also.                                                 
      "Write folder name
    .Range("A" & NR) = fPath
    .Range("A" & NR).Select
    If AddLinks Then .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, _
           Address:=fPath, _
            TextToDisplay:=fPath"   But in hyperlink i want to show only sub folder name instead of full path. please help

Comment: Replace `TextToDisplay:=fPath` with `TextToDisplay:=Split(fPath, "\")(UBound(Split(fPath, "\")) - 1)`

Comment: Any more help needed you'll need to raise a new question. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Hi i'm not sure what do you mean with Blank Row for a subfolder. But i think if you add `NR = NR+1` in the Subfolder Loop, it should wor fine.

```
 'Files under sub dir
     Set oDir = oFS.GetFolder(fPath)
     For Each oSub In oDir.SubFolders
          NR = NR + 1
          Call FindFilesAndAddLinks(oSub.Path & "\", fType, NR, AddLinks)
     Next oSub
```

Comment: i Mean, if  there are 10 sub folders in directory, i want blank row at end of each sub folder files.

Comment: Hi is it possible to show the SUB FOLDER NAME in first row of each sub folder? please help

Comment: Does this not produce a lot of blank lines when it scans empty subfolders?

Comment: Yes, but it will show like windows folder you can easily find a files. That is the reason i have asked this.

Comment: I was responding to Moosli's original answer. Now you want the folder name then blanks make sense. :-)

Comment: I want to show Subfolder name then heperlink at end blank row. then next subfolder name-Hyperlink at end blank row